# Thin wrapper for read_xlsx function works with defaults, but not with custom file location

Tags: r, tidyverse, readxl

I'm creating a simple little time-saver wrapper function that pre-fills out some standard file locations, etc. for importing an Excel file using `readxl::read_xlsx`.  It works exactly as expected with the defaults, however, when I try to use it at the console with a different file location I get the following error.

`Error in read_space_program(path = "inst/extdata/space_program.xlsx") : 
  unused argument (path = "inst/extdata/space_program.xlsx")`

I've tried adding `, ...`, as suggested on StackOverflow by those with similar error messages, to extend the arguments but it does not fix the problem.  This is the code I am running:

```r
read_space_program <-
    function(file_location = "inst/extdata/space_program.xlsx",
             sheet_name = "Program",
             skip_rows = 5, ...) {
        readxl::read_xlsx(
            path = file_location,
            sheet = sheet_name,
            col_names = TRUE,
            skip = skip_rows
        ) # first five rows skipped to allow for project information
    }
```

Without uploading the entire .xlsx file, suffice to say that I use this particular file all the time and it is not the source of the problem.  It loads fine with this exact code when I run it like this: `read_space_program()`, however when I test it by feeding the exact same file location into it at the console with this: `read_space_program(file_location = "inst/extdata/space_program.xlsx")`, I get the error above.  This error probably has something to do with something basic, I'm pretty sure, but cannot figure it out.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error when adapting your function to read an excel file on my computer (Windows 7, R 3.5.3, readxl 1.3.1).  Both cases work for me.

Comment: Okay, that spurred me to keep plugging at it.  I cleaned out my environment (which I know should have been one of the first things to do) and then re-ran the code; and it worked!  So I must have had some artifact from developing things that was causing an error (though honestly, I don't know what).  Thanks so much for taking the time to run it.  It let me know that at least I wasn't going crazy.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by an artifact of development in my environment.  Cleaning the environment allowed the code to run.